# MySQL return default value if dataset is empty

Tags: mysql, r, select, coalesce

I am trying to query a database using:

```
SELECT coalesce(value, "NA") as value 
FROM mytable FORCE INDEX (chrs) FORCE INDEX (sites) 
WHERE chrom = 1 AND site = 120
```

This query works fine if I have an entry in the database. However, if the entry is not found it returns an empty dataset. I would like to change the query so that if it isn't found in the database table it will still return some sort of value (for "value") rather than an empty dataset

Comment: can you post some relevant data?

Answer (score 1):

how about you add a UNION?

```
(   SELECT coalesce(value, "NA") as value 
    FROM mytable FORCE INDEX (chrs) FORCE INDEX (sites) 
    WHERE chrom = 1 AND site = 120
)
UNION ALL
(   SELECT 'NA' as value
    FROM mytable
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (   SELECT coalesce(value, "NA") as value 
        FROM mytable FORCE INDEX (chrs) FORCE INDEX (sites) 
        WHERE chrom = 1 AND site = 120
    )
)
```

or if you want to do the coalesce once so that way you can change the returned part if null more easily you can select from it like so.

```
SELECT COALESCE(value, "NA") as value
FROM
(   
    (   SELECT value
        FROM mytable FORCE INDEX (chrs) FORCE INDEX (sites) 
        WHERE chrom = 1 AND site = 120
    )
    UNION ALL
    (   SELECT NULL as value
        FROM mytable
        WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (   SELECT value as value 
            FROM mytable FORCE INDEX (chrs) FORCE INDEX (sites) 
            WHERE chrom = 1 AND site = 120
        )
    )
) t
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbc1c/9)

Answer (score 0):

One (ugly) way to do it : create a table with only one line (doesn't matter the data in that table), then use :

```
SELECT coalesce(m.value, "NA") from oneline left join mytable m on m.chrom=1 and m.site=120;
```

Here's what you get :

```
mysql> select * from oneline;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable;
+-------+-------+------+
| value | chrom | site |
+-------+-------+------+
| test  |     1 |  120 |
+-------+-------+------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT coalesce(m.value, "NA") from oneline left join mytable m on m.chrom=1 and m.site=120;
+-------------------------+
| coalesce(m.value, "NA") |
+-------------------------+
| test                    |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT coalesce(m.value, "NA") from oneline left join mytable m on m.chrom=1 and m.site=119;
+-------------------------+
| coalesce(m.value, "NA") |
+-------------------------+
| NA                      |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```